# Remove a laravel sheduling task

Tags: php, laravel, command, scheduled-tasks

I use laravel's command and task scheduling to check shared online 3D printers's status. I use below code to start the scheduling task to check the device status every 10 minutes. But I want to remove the scheduling task when the printer is off line.

```
$schedule->command(DeviceCheckCommand::class, ['--force'])->everyTenMinutes();
```

I've read the [laravel doc Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#defining-schedules) entirely, but I cannot find any info about how to remove a scheduling task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You better save printer's status in a file or database and check for the status before executing another command:

**Inside DeviceCheckCommand.php:**

```
public function handle()
{
    // Your code

    if ($printerStatus == 'Offline') {
        Storage::put('PrinterIsOffline.info', 'Yes');
    } else {
       Storage::delete('PrinterIsOffline.info');
    }
}
```

**Inside Kernel.php:**

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    if (!Storage::exists('PrinterIsOffline.info')) {
        $schedule->command(DeviceCheckCommand::class, ['--force'])->everyTenMinutes();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear. My qustion is not about when to start a scheduling task. In my question I mean, when a printer switch from online to offline, how to remove the scheduling task which is on the run.

Comment: The command is calling once every then minute, so if you want to cancel the command during its log-time operation, you should check for printer's status during the operation inside DeviceCommandCheck. I think this is not rerated to task scheduler at all. This is the function of your command to throw an exception in case printer is offline.

Comment: Your response solved his problem but didn't respond to his question. The question is, how we stop the task scheduler to run our task. When you're managing crons, the only thing you need to do is to remove the cron entry from the crontab file. But no similar option is mentioned in the documentation.